# How to use Firebase hosting preview channel to test cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a back-end server built using firebase cloud functions and I'm trying to test it and have a shareable test link without having to deploy to the live channel.

I found this https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/test-preview-deploy#preview-channels but when I follow the instructions, it only deploys the static public folder. So any changes I make to the back-end have no effect. I can use the back-end using the preview URL but it's always the same version as the live build.

Am I missing something? Or is preview channels for static content only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct, preview channels currently only support static content + Firebase Hosting configuration. One way to work around this (admittedly not ideal), is to deploy the old and new versions of your Cloud Function as separate functions (e.g. `app` and `appV2`) and change the preview channel to point to the different function.

Comment: I was hoping to use preview channels for setting up deploy previews. Any idea, how we can do that to deploy these functions automatically?

Comment: Is it possible to add a guide for this process?